# Bad math environment delimiter

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

I'm getting a bad math environment delimiter error and I don't know why. Here is the part where I'm getting error:

```
\\(\forall x \in U: \tilde{M}  = \{(\(x\); \mu_{\tilde{M}}(x)) \in [0,1]\}\\)
```

I hope you can help me! Thanks for any help in advance!

Best regards,
Ben

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) Please always post full minimal examples what people can copy and compile without having to add something.

Comment: You are basically doing math mode inside math mode, what are you doing here `{(\(x\); \mu_{\tilde{M}}(x)) \in [0,1]}`?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something similar to

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\forall x \in U: \tilde{M} = 
 (x);\quad \mu_{\tilde{M}}(x) \in [0,1]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note this is *displayed* math, `\(...\)` gives you inline math. Might be easier to distinguish by using `$...$`